# How do I write printed for loop values to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I would like to save the printed moving average to a csv file named "LabelX".

```py
    import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import csv
from statistics import mean
from itertools import islice         
df = pd.read_csv("5714604.csv");
Input = df['water_level(ft below land surface)'];
N = 50
cumsum, moving_aves = [0], []

for i, x in enumerate(Input, 1):
    cumsum.append(cumsum[i-1] + x)
    if i>=N:
        moving_ave = (cumsum[i] - cumsum[i-N])/N
        #can do stuff with moving_ave here
        moving_aves.append(moving_ave)
        print(moving_ave)
```

The output looks like this which is fine.
185.78499999999997
185.77059999999997
185.7552
185.7384
185.72120000000004
185.7038
185.68640000000002
185.67
185.65439999999998
185.6398

I just need it saved to a csv file in incremental rows not columns until completion.

Comment: A CSV is just a comma-separated file. So you can open the file, write your value, and go to the next line to make each entry in a separate row, instead of a separate column

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the `print` function help entry you can see that you can specify a file where it should write to:

> help(print)
>   Help on built-in function print in module builtins:
>
> print(...)
>
> print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
>
> ```
> Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
> Optional keyword arguments:
> file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
> sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
> end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
> flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
> ```

So you can `open` the csv file pass it and after you finished you close it.

e.g.

```
>>> f = open("test.txt", "w")
>>> print("Hello World", file=f)
>>> f.close()
```

Another solution would be to use `write` instead of `print`, because this is what `write` is for.

Tip: To open and close a file properly you should use the `with` syntax:
e.g.

```
with open(path, "w") as file:
    file.write("Hello world")
```